# Counting how many characters your name have

Tags: python, if-statement

I started learning Python since yesterday and I made a simple game using python. It counts how many characters the name has that you type in. But I keep getting wrong answers. Can anyone verify my code.My code is as follows. Thank you.

```
print('What is your name?')

Name = input()

print('How many alphabets does your name have?')

Char = input()

if Char == len(Name):

    print('Good job')

else:

    print('What?')
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. Try `if int(Char) == len(Name):` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('What is your name?')

Name = input()
print('How many alphabets does your name have?')

Char = input()
print(type(Char))

if Char is len(Name):

    print('Good job')

else:

    print('What?')

Char = int(Char)
print(type(Char))
if Char is len(Name):

    print('Good job')

else:

    print('What?')
```

Just have a look at the above code and you can understand that since input() provides a string and you tried to compare a string with an integer, it didn't satisfy the if condition. So it had gone to the else and printed the "What"

Find the output of my above code below.

```
How many alphabets does your name have?
6
<class 'str'>
What?
<class 'int'>
Good job
```

Hope this helps to give you a clearer picture.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Henry, the `Char` variable is a **string** and you are comparing it with an **integer** which will always return **FALSE**.

You have to use `int()` function which converts any data type to an integer like this:

```
print('What is your name?')

Name = input()

print('How many alphabets does your name have?')

Char = input()

if int(Char) == len(Name):

    print('Good job')

else:

    print('What?')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are evaluating a string with a number and that doesn't work, so if you turn `Char` into an integer with `int`, you can compare the two.